# Porque una consulta sql me trae datos pero cuando le pongo una cláusula where no me trae nada?

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo 2 consultas a una base de datos sql server:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La primera me trae todos los datos bien:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero la segunda con la cláusula where no me trae nada!!!

La llamada al método la hago así cuando quiero que me traiga todo:

```
var objetos = await consulta.SelectFromDatabase(conexion, "SELECT  [ACTIVO_ACCION],ESTADO_ACCION FROM xxxx");
```

y así cuando quiero que me lo traiga con el where :

```
var objetos = await consulta.SelectFromDatabase(conexion, "SELECT  [ACTIVO_ACCION],ESTADO_ACCION FROM xxxx where ACTIVO_ACCION=13");
```

Y el método que uso para el llamado en ambos casos es este :

```
public async Task<List<object>> SelectFromDatabase(Conexion con,string consulta)
    {


        List<object> resultados = new List<object>();

        try
        {
            bool hayConsulta = consulta != null ? true : false;

            if (hayConsulta)
            {
                bool servidor = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(con.Servidor) ? true : false;

                bool bd = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(con.BD) ? true : false;

                bool usuario = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(con.Usuario) ? true : false;

                bool clave = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(con.Password) ? true : false;



                if (servidor && bd && usuario && clave )
                {

                    using (var conexion=new SqlConnection("Server=" + con.Servidor + ";Initial Catalog=" + con.BD + ";User Id=" + con.Usuario + ";Password=" + con.Password + ";Persist Security Info=True;"))
                    {
                         await conexion.OpenAsync();

                        using (var comando=new SqlCommand(consulta,conexion))
                        {
                          int filas=  await comando.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

                            using (var reader=await comando.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                            {
                                while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                                {

                                    foreach (var item in reader.Cast<DbDataRecord>())
                                    {
                                        for (int i = 0; i < item.FieldCount; i++)
                                        {
                                            if (item.GetValue(i) != null)
                                            {

                                                var anonimo = new { columna = item.GetName(i), valor = item.GetValue(i) };


                                                resultados.Add(anonimo);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }  


                    return resultados;

                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            return null;
        }


    }
```

Entonces si es el mismo método porque no devuelve nada cuando le pongo where? . Ya hice debuggin y el problema se da desde el SQLCommando que no trae filas , trae -1 , por alguna razón no conecta o no trae los datos cuando se le pone el where!!!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que tipos de datos tiene tu tabla?

Comment: int,varchar,datetime,tinynt,uniqueidentifier

Comment: activo_accion es varchar?

Comment: No es un int. Intente con otra tabla donde la primary key es un varchar y en ese caso le puse  where dato= 'dato'  entre comillas simples pero tampoco funciona.

Comment: Una opción es que al momento de especificar el `where = 13`, lo este tomando como `string`; prueba a ponerlo como `var objetos = await consulta.SelectFromDatabase(conexion, $"SELECT  [ACTIVO_ACCION],ESTADO_ACCION FROM xxxx where ACTIVO_ACCION={13}");`

Comment: Ya lo intente pero no tiene nada que ver con comillas simples o si es string o entero. La consulta le llega bien al SQLCommand pero no tiene explicación de que por un simple where no sea capaz de traer la data

Comment: Probaste "SELECT  ACTIVO_ACCION,ESTADO_ACCION FROM xxxx where ACTIVO_ACCION=13" . Quizás los caracteres especiales en la string te estén dando el problema.

Comment: @NicolasAlejandroGottig   Si fuera eso la primera consulta tampoco traería data

Comment: porque en SelectFromDatabase() pasas por parametro un objeto de Conexion, eso no esta bueno, la conexion deberia configurarse en el connection string

Comment: @LeandroTuttini Porque SelectFromDatabase() es un método en un paquete Nuget que hice. Por eso necesito pasarla como parámetro también me hace falta parametizar la consulta. Pero de todos modos apenas estoy en pruebas así que quizas busque otra forma de manejar eso pero por ahorita me interesa que funcione.

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero que voy a recomendar es que esto

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    return null;
}
```

NUNCA, no se deja un catch sin hacer nada, menos cuando te conectas a datos, puedes si necesitas loguear a un archivo de texto, o el event view de windows, pero debes realizar algo con el exception, capturarlo para no hacer nada y anularlo es una pesima idea. 
Despues falla la app y nunca te enteras de porque suceden las cosas

Creo que complicas mucho el codigo si necesidad

```
public async Task<List<T>> SelectFromDatabase(Conexion con,string consulta) where T: class, new
{
    List<T> resultados = new List<T>();

    try
    {
        string connstring = "Server=" + con.Servidor + ";Initial Catalog=" + con.BD + ";User Id=" + con.Usuario + ";Password=" + con.Password + ";Persist Security Info=True;"
        using (var conexion=new SqlConnection(connstring))
        {
            await conexion.OpenAsync();

            var comando = new SqlCommand(consulta, conexion)

            var reader=await comando.ExecuteReaderAsync()

            while (await reader.ReadAsync())
            {
                //resto codigo
                //debes instancia un T para crear una instancia 
            }
        }

        return resultados;

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //aqui logueas el problema en un archivo
        return null;
    }

}
```

las validaciones podrias quitarlas, dejalo que arme el connection string, si algun valor no se especifica fallara y obtendras el mensaje que es lo mismo que validar absolutamente todos

No esta bueno retornar un `object` deberias usar `generic` para poder devolver clases tipadas como respuesta

Como en este articulo que usa `reflection` para armar la entidad en base a los datos de la consulta

[Simplify ADO.NET Using Generic Methods and Reflection](https://blog.fairwaytech.com/simplify-ado.net-using-generic-methods-and-reflection)

Usar el `ExecuteNonQueryAsync()` para obtener el numero de filas no es necesario ya que con el reader puede iterarlas sin necesidad de conocer cuantas retorna

Si necesitas conocer la cantidad previamente ejecuta la consulta

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM xxxx where [ACTIVO_ACCION] = 13
```

usando el `ExecuteScalar()`

Tambien valida sino necesitas definir los nombre de los campos entre `[]` puede que eso cause problemas

Para validar si es la consulta lo mejor que puedes hacer es una ejecucion bien simple

```
string sql = @"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM xxxx where [ACTIVO_ACCION] = @accion"; 

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connection string")) 
{ 
    conn.Open(); 

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn); 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accion", 13); 

    int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()); 

}
```

define un connection string directo sin armarlo con variables para estar bien seguro que te conectas a la db correcta y no a otra

Comment: Hombre! pues gracias por las recomendaciones pero no me responden porque pasa el problema  de que cuando se ejecuta el ExecuteNonQueryAsync() no me trae filas si le paso un where en la consulta!!!

Comment: agregue codigo al final, valida ejecutando una consulta simple, evitando armar el connection string sino que lo defines fijo en un string, si tienes varias dbs puede que este conectandote a una diferente

Comment: La consulta esta bien y el connection string también esta bien. La consulta la copie tal y como esta en sql server. Ya la probé con []  y sin []  ya hice todas esa pruebas. El problema es que el ExecuteNonQueryAsync() trae la data cuando no tiene where pero con where no trae la data. Y no entiendo porque diablos puede ser. Ese es el problema.

Comment: Ni la consulta ni el connection string son el problema.

Comment: Leandro porque en el código uso de una vez el ExecuteReaderAsync()??  No es necesario usar el ExecuteNonQueryAsync()  antes????

Comment: No el ExecuteNonQueryAsync() esta de mas, solo aplicaria el ExecuteScalar() si defines un COUNT() en el SELECT, sino es directo el ExecuteReader(). Por eso para saber si retorna los registros no uses el ExecuteNonQuery()

Answer (score 0):

Al final pude solucionarlo. Resulta que no era necesario ejecutar el método ExecuteNonQueryAsync(),ni tampoco el ReadAsync(), el  código que me funcionó quedo así:

```
public async Task<List<object>> SelectFromDatabase(Conexion con,string consulta)
    {


        List<object> resultados = new List<object>();

        try
        {
                    using (var conexion=new SqlConnection("Server=" + con.Servidor + ";Initial Catalog=" + con.BD + ";User Id=" + con.Usuario + ";Password=" + con.Password + ";Persist Security Info=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"))
                    {

                        await conexion.OpenAsync();

                        using (var comando=new SqlCommand(consulta,conexion))
                        {
                            var reader = await comando.ExecuteReaderAsync();


                                foreach (var item in reader.Cast<DbDataRecord>())
                                {
                                    for (int i = 0; i < item.FieldCount; i++)
                                    {
                                        if (item.GetValue(i) != null)
                                        {

                                            var anonimo = new { columna = item.GetName(i), valor = item.GetValue(i) };


                                            resultados.Add(anonimo);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                        }
                    }  


                    return resultados;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            var anonimo = new { columna = "error", valor = e.ToString() };

            resultados.Add(anonimo);

            return resultados;
        }


    }
```